# Onclick on li not triggered but li is focused

Tags: javascript, css, events

I have a strange problem when I'm working on ul/li elements.

With a very simple html/css like this

```css
li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

li:focus {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 30px -20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="collection">
  <li class="collection-item" onclick="window.alert('Click on li collection')" tabindex="0">Item 1</li>
  <li class="collection-item"  onclick="window.alert('Click on li collection')" tabindex="0">Item 2</li>
  <li class="collection-item"  onclick="window.alert('Click on li collection')" tabindex="0">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

P.S. To try the code: https://jsfiddle.net/vcbmbjx0/, seems the css of snippet didn't works fine.

What I want is to change the margin when the li element is focused, but it seems that this change broke the emit of the click event. (The click is not triggered when I click in the middle of item 1 and item 2, but the focus effect of item 2 is triggered...)

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: All your events are being triggered fine, I do not see the issue? o.0

Comment: I'm confused, your JSFiddle seems to be working as you explained. Is this not correct?

Comment: `:focus` works fine when you tab to each `li`...

Comment: The focus event fires before the click. With your CSS you move the item out of the click point of the mouse, so the click event won't fire

Comment: You can use the `onmousedown` event instead of `onclick`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The margin on focus seem to be moving your element away before the click happens.

If you remove the margin, then this works:

```
.collection-item {
  cursor: pointer;
  &:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  &:focus {
    background-color: red;
    //margin: 30px -20px;  --> offending line
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vcbmbjx0/2/

or mouse down works as explained above:

https://jsfiddle.net/vcbmbjx0/3/

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will use the mousedown and touchstart events.